# How to initialize properties from a base class?

Tags: flutter

I've got a number of classes that extend a base class, and I'm having problems getting the members from the base class initialized in the default constructor.

I have tried listing the fields in the default constructor, with and without the 'this.' qualifier.

I had similar issues with fields in other classes not being set, but that was corrected by placing 'this.' in front of the fields.  However, if I apply the 'this.' qualifier to the inherited fields, I get an error saying the fields are not in the enclosing class.

Base class:

```
import 'package:randomizer/model/includecondition.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/setup.dart';

abstract class Includable {
  List<IncludeCondition> includedWhen;
  List<IncludeCondition> includedIf;
  List<IncludeCondition> mustIncludeWhen;
  List<IncludeCondition> excludeWhen;

  Includable(
      {this.includedWhen,
      this.includedIf,
      this.mustIncludeWhen,
      this.excludeWhen});
}
```

Derived class:

```
import 'package:randomizer/model/exclusiongroup.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/includable.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/includecondition.dart';
import 'package:randomizer/model/item.dart';

class Selection extends Includable {
  String name;
  int minNumToSelect;
  int maxNumToSelect;
  List<Item> items;
  List<ExclusionGroup> exclusionGroups;

  Selection(
      {this.name,
      this.items,
      this.exclusionGroups,
      this.minNumToSelect,
      this.maxNumToSelect,
      includedWhen,
      includedIf,
      mustIncludeWhen,
      excludeWhen});

  factory Selection.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    Selection result = Selection(
      name: map['name'] ?? '',
      minNumToSelect:
          map.keys.contains('minNumToSelect') ? map['minNumToSelect'] : 1,
      maxNumToSelect:
          map.keys.contains('maxNumToSelect') ? map['maxNumToSelect'] : 1,
      items: map.keys.contains('items') ? Item.fromList(map['items']) : null,
      exclusionGroups: map.keys.contains('exclusionGroups')
          ? ExclusionGroup.fromList(map['exclusionGroups'])
          : null,
      includedWhen: map.keys.contains('includedWhen')
          ? IncludeCondition.fromList(map['includedWhen'])
          : null,
      includedIf: map.keys.contains('includedIf')
          ? IncludeCondition.fromList(map['includedIf'])
          : null,
      mustIncludeWhen: map.keys.contains('mustIncludeWhen')
          ? IncludeCondition.fromList(map['mustIncludeWhen'])
          : null,
      excludeWhen: map.keys.contains('excludedWhen')
          ? IncludeCondition.fromList(map['excludedWhen'])
          : null,
    );

    return result;
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to set all of these fields in the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call super constructor in your inherited class. That is the reason why super class members has not been initialized.
In your `Selection` class constructor you should do:

```
Selection(
      {this.name,
      this.items,
      this.exclusionGroups,
      this.minNumToSelect,
      this.maxNumToSelect,
      // specify the type  List<IncludeCondition> here is optional
      List<IncludeCondition> includedWhen,
      List<IncludeCondition> includedIf,
      List<IncludeCondition> mustIncludeWhen,
      List<IncludeCondition> excludeWhen}) : super( 
           includedWhen: includedWhen,
           includedIf : includedIf
           mustIncludeWhen : mustIncludeWhen,
           excludeWhen : excludeWhen
      ) ;
```

In `: super( ... )` lines we call super class constructor and then the super class members are initialized.
You can do the same in others inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that the main reason you're having problems is the fact that you're extending an abstract class instead of implementing it. Change `extends` to `implements` in the `Select` class. Then you'll have errors because your `Select` class needs to have and override the all properties in the abstract class.

Code:

```dart
class Selection implements Includable {
  String name;
  int minNumToSelect;
  int maxNumToSelect;
  List<Item> items;
  List<ExclusionGroup> exclusionGroups;

  @override
  List<IncludeCondition> excludeWhen;

  @override
  List<IncludeCondition> includedIf;

  @override
  List<IncludeCondition> mustIncludeWhen;

  @override
  List<IncludeCondition> excludeWhen;

  Selection(
      {this.name,
      this.items,
      this.exclusionGroups,
      this.minNumToSelect,
      this.maxNumToSelect,
      this.includedWhen,
      this.includedIf,
      this.mustIncludeWhen,
      this.excludeWhen});

}
```